# How to read large data bits as bytes of data in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i have large bits of binary data say (`11111111000000001010101011111111`) . I have to divide this data in byte of data (8 bits). Such that a group of bytes are formed.

After grouped as 8 bits of data a, I want first 8 bits of data as first output. Then after reading those first 8 bits I want to further read next 8 bits and so on.

for example if  my data is ( `11111111000000001010101011111111`), then i want to read first `11111111` then `00000000` then `10101010` and lastly `11111111`.

Comment: You need to provide more details, What is 11111111000000001010101011111111 held within? A bytearray?  bitarray? string?  What do you mean by 11111111? the integer 255? a string of '1' ?

Comment: "i have large bits of binary data" <--- where??

Comment: @rory.ap Apparently `IEnumerable<bit>` :)

Comment: I tried to hold the data as string and also as an bit array but was not successful. Instead I was able to read only 1 new bit from the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your data stored as string and you want to keep using it as string, you can do the following:

```
        string s = "11111111000000001010101011111111";

        List<string> yourStringList = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i = i + 8)
        {
            yourStringList.Add(s.Substring(i, 8));
        }

        foreach (string st in yourStringList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(st); //DO WHATEVER YOU NEED WITH YOUR STRING HERE
        }
```

Then you can iterate the list with a foreach loop and you will have access to your data formatted as you want.

Comment: glad it helped. if you are new to this community, dont forget to upvote and accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
string bits = "1000101010101011111101010101010";
byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
int byteCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i += 8)
{
    bytes[byteCount] = Convert.ToByte(bits.Substring(i, 8), 2);
    byteCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to *enumerate* through your string like a byte array you could do:

```
var someBytes = "11111111000000001010101011111111";
foreach (string byteString in EnumerateBytes(someBytes)) 
{ 
}
```

And `EnumerateBytes`:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateBytes(string bytesString)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < bytesString.Length; i = i + 8) { yield return bytesString.Substring(i, 8); }
}
```